# I get an error in python code while running

Tags: python, runtime-error, runtime, python-3.7

So the program is supposed to ask the user to enter their yearly salary, and then it divides the Yearly salary of the user by 52 to produce the Weekly salary, and then it displays it. This is the code I've written so far and everytime I run it, I get the following `runtime error`:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str"

#### Code:

```
AnnualSalary = float(input("Please enter your Yearly salary: "))

print("Yearly salary is: " + AnnualSalary)
WeeklySalary = AnnualSalary/52

print("According to your yearly salary, Your weekly salary is " + WeeklySalary)
```

Answer (score 0):

While printing you need to convert Annual salary to string by wrapping the variable around str(AnnualSalary). That should solve your problem. The same goes for WeeklySalary too.

Because print is looking for a string.

```
AnnualSalary = float(input("Please enter your Yearly salary: "))

print("Yearly salary is: " + str(AnnualSalary)) 

WeeklySalary = AnnualSalary/52

print("According to your yearly salary, Your weekly salary is " + str(WeeklySalary))
```

Answer (score 0):

see

```
print("Yearly salary is: " + AnnualSalary) 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str"
```

something is wrong with the type here, and the error is when it is expecting str it got float instead,  so we just need to convert float to str.

```
print("Yearly salary is: " + str(AnnualSalary))
print("According to your yearly salary, Your weekly salary is " + str(AnnualSalary/52)
```